# MKPointAnnotation to MKMapItem

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkmapitem

I'm getting an error "Could not cast value of type 'NSKVONotifying_MKPointAnnotation' to 'MKMapItem'" when trying to open Apple Maps for directions.  I'm new at this and I've been piecing together code to try to make it work.

```
struct Location {
    let agencyId: String
    let agencyEventId: String
    let agencyEventSubTypeCode: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let agencyEventTypeCode: String
}

func multiPoint() {

    for receivedEvent in receivedEventsList {
        mapEventLatitude = receivedEvent.latitude!
        mapEventLongitude = receivedEvent.longitude!
        latDouble = ("\(mapEventLatitude))" as NSString).doubleValue
        longDouble = ("\(mapEventLongitude))" as NSString).doubleValue
        multiMapAgencyEventSubTypeCode = receivedEvent.agencyEventSubtypeCode!
        multiMapAgencyId = receivedEvent.agencyId!
        multiMapAgencyEventId = receivedEvent.agencyEventId!
        multiMapAgencyEventTypeCode = receivedEvent.agencyEventTypeCode!

        let locations = [
            Location(agencyId: multiMapAgencyId, agencyEventId: multiMapAgencyEventId, agencyEventSubTypeCode: multiMapAgencyEventSubTypeCode, latitude: latDouble, longitude: longDouble, agencyEventTypeCode: multiMapAgencyEventTypeCode)
            ]


        for location in locations {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            annotation.title = location.agencyId
            annotation.subtitle = multiMapAgencyEventSubTypeCode
            multiEventMap?.addAnnotation(annotation)
            eventTypeNumber = ("\(multiMapAgencyEventTypeCode))" as NSString).intValue
        }
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseIdentifier = "annotationView"
    let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        view.markerTintColor = UIColor.blue
        view.glyphText = "x"
        view.displayPriority = .required
        view.clusteringIdentifier = nil
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    return view
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let location =  view.annotation as! MKMapItem
    let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
    location.openInMaps(launchOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add your annotations to your map, you added them as `MKPointAnnotation`, so the cast to `MKMapItem` will obviously fail.

I’d suggest that instead of creating `MKPointAnnotation`, create either a `MKPlacemark` or create your own subclass of `MKPlacemark` that includes the additional properties that you’re interested in. Then your `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` can

- cast the `view.annotation` to your placemark type;
- create a `MKMapItem` using that placemark; and then
- `mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions:)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As stated, I’m very new to developing so I’ll be trying to figure out how to piece that together.